# 16 number puzzles on a blackboard

Tags: word, pattern, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence, sequence

I have left you some number puzzles on the blackboard. Solve them and let me know what they spell.

[image: 16 Math Puzzles]

Hint:

> The final answer is two words and is something from Harry Potter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> TUTSHILL TORNADOS

The individual answers, starting from top left and moving right, are

> 19 (subtract 19 each time)
>  20 (multiply by 5)
>  19 (a^2 + b)
>  18 (sum of 2 opposite triangles)
>  7 (multiply 2 vertices, divide by left vertice)
>  8  (square of opposite number minus 1)
>  11 (sum of adjacent sides)
>  11 (a*b + a + b)
>  19 (circle is 4, triangle is 2, rectangle is 1)
>  14 (base 8)
>  17 (rotate 180 degrees)
>  13 (sum of opposites minus bottom right gives top left)
>  0 (just calculate)
>  3 (just algebra)
>  14 (just calculate)
>  18 (sum of two left diagonals gives number on top)

Then use A-Z = 0-25.

Comment: Correct. You got all of them right.

Comment: If you want to solve more, I've posted some letter puzzles. Some are similar, others are new. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94388/12-more-blackboard-puzzles-letter-puzzles

Answer (score 4):

Solving the number puzzles:

1. > $19$ (descending multiples of 19)
2. > $20$ (multiplying the left number by 5 to get the right one)
3. > $19$ (square of first number plus second number gives third number)
4. > $18$ (each outer number is the sum of the two inner numbers *furthest* from it)
5. > $7$ (bottom left of each triangle is the product of the other two divided by 2)
6. > $8$ (each larger number is the square of the opposite smaller number minus 1)
7. > $11$ (each larger number is the sum of the two adjacent smaller numbers)
8. > $11$ (add 1 to everything and this becomes simply products)
9. See Jens's answer - I didn't manage to get this one.
10. > $14$ (base 8 on the left, base 10 on the right)
11. See Jens's answer - I didn't manage to get this one.
12. > $13$ (both diagonals give the same sum)
13. > $0$ (direct calculation)
14. > $3$ (solving the first two equations gives A=30 and B=10)
15. > $14$ (direct calculation)
16. > $18$ (moving from southwest to northeast by making each new cell the sum of the two touching it)

Turning the numbers into letters:

> `S  T  S  R`
>  `G  H  K  K`
>  `S  N  Q  M`
>     `C  N  R`

The final step, motivated by the appearance of

> no vowels, but quite a few letters that precede vowels, like S and N (this also explains the mysterious zero),

is to

> add 1 to all the numbers (or Caesar-shift the letters by 1) to get:
>
>  `T  U  T  S`
>  `H  I  L  L`
>  `T  O  R  N`
>  `A  D  O  S`

yielding the solution.

Comment: You got it! If you want to solve more, I've posted some letter puzzles. Some are similar, others are new. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94388/12-more-blackboard-puzzles-letter-puzzles