# 12 more blackboard puzzles (letter puzzles)

Tags: word, pattern, letters, letter-sequence, sequence

I have previously posted [number puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94383/16-number-puzzles-on-a-blackboard). This time it's letter puzzles. Some clues have a Harry Potter theme.

[image: 12 puzzles]

Hint:

> The answer is a 6-letter word

Hint 2:

> HAGRID = SZTIRW

Hint 3:

> [image: zgyzhs]

Comment: Just a comment - if the “hints” are more or less mandatory then include them in the puzzle and not as a hint (the second hint seems pretty close to this); if they’re NOT mandatory, it’s recommended you wait a while and let folks have a chance at solving it without them. See also https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5005/when-should-i-add-hints-to-my-puzzle and its answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**COMPLETE SOLUTION:**

Answers provided for all 12 clues, including 4 found by @Randal'Thor...

> 1 = **X** (In A1Z26 each row sums to 24; the 24th letter is X)
>
>  2 = **L** (Alternate letters spell the words WIZARD anti-clockwise and MUGG**L**E (JK Rowling's word for a non-magical person) clockwise, with the ‘L’ missing)
>
>  3 = **W** (Bottom letters are initials of the 4 ‘Marauders’ who created the "Marauders' Map" first seen in the third HP book), and the top letter the initial of their nickname: **J**ames **P**otter = **P**rongs, **R**emus **L**upin = **M**oony, **S**irius **B**lack = **P**adfoot, and **P**eter **P**ettigrew = **WORMTAIL**, which begins with W)
>
>  4 = **V** (Sequence snakes down a column, up the next, etc., moving 3 letters on each time) (also found by @Randal'Thor)
>
>  5 = **R** (Sequence is +2, +3, +4 and then +5)
>
>  6 = **H** (Each triangle represents the initials of one of the 3 main characters of the HP books: **H**ermione **J**ean **G**ranger, **R**onald **B**ilius **W**easley, and **HARRY** **J**ames **P**otter, which yields H)
>
>  7 = **H** (Sought-for letter is midway between the pair of letters) (found by @Randal'Thor)
>
>  8 = **K** (Sequence is alternate terms of +7, -4)
>
>  9 = **I** (Opposing pairs of letters add to the central S (19) in A1Z26) (method found by @Randal'Thor, though his answer is incorrect!)
>
>  10 = **L** (Arithmetic with Roman numerals) (found by @Randal'Thor)
>
>  11 = **F** (Letter on left is 5 on from letter on right, moving from Z to A when required) (found by @Randal'Thor)
>
>  12 = **G** (The circles hide four 4-letter creatures from the HP books - find them by choosing a letter from the first circle, then choosing the next clockwise from each subsequent circle. This produces OGRE, TOAD, STAG and FRO**G** if the missing letter is a G.)

These give us the letters:

> **XLWVRHHKILFG**

This letter sequence:

> has been encoded with a substitution cipher where each of the first 13 letters of the alphabet are reflected about the halfway point (M/N) and substituted with the letter in the second half of the alphabet that is the same distance from Z as the original letter was from A.
>
>  i.e. A = Z, B = Y, C = X, etc.

Translated, this reveals:

> **CODE IS SPROUT** ('Sprout' being the name of the Head of Hufflepuff House and professor of the magical plant science Herbology in the Harry Potter series).

Comment: All are correct except #12. It is a good solution but not the intended one.

Comment: @eyl327 Is it a Harry Potter one?

Comment: In a way, it is Harry Potter themed. Does not require any knowledge of Harry Potter, though.

Comment: @eyl327 Aha, got that one now! Nice puzzle clue that one :)

Comment: You got it. I added hints for the final step.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer for the clues:

1. > 
2. > 
3. > 
4. > $V$ (in each column the letters are advancing by 3 places through the alphabet as you go up or down)
5. > 
6. > 
7. > $H$ (the letter on the right is exactly in between, the midpoint, of the two on the left)
8. I wonder if this might be something to do with

   > each letter representing one of the seven Harry Potter books, somehow. Just a hunch.
9. > $G$ (treating letters as numbers, the sum of each opposite pair is the one in the middle)
10. > $L$ (arithmetic with Roman numerals)
11. > $F$ (the letter on the right is five before the one on the left in the alphabet, cycling if necessary)
12. > 

Partially filled grid:

> `?  ?  ?  V`
>  `?  ?  H  ?`
>  `G  L  F  ?`

Comment: The ones you have filled in (4, 7, 9, 10, 11) are correct.